# Best iOS design pattern for basic one view showing/hiding

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I tested some own design patterns but not satisfied because a bit complex compared to the task to achieve..

I have a playground, using pure C++ stuff without UI.
At the bottom, I'd like to have only a basic button on which the user can click to show a menu (basically a view from a .xib)

I tried to do that with two view, one "calling" show/hide methods of the other... A mess, using tagged instances etc.

How would you achieve that without a toolbar which would take too much space on the screen ?

Many thanks for your advices and experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right you could read this: 
[Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

I would recommend you to have one view controller for each view in your application. So with that said you make one view controller and a view (programatically or Interface Builder) that contains the button, and on click you would use the technique I linked to present the popover/modal view controller's view.

I think the documentation from Apple is good but I can provide some tutorials too:

- http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/
- http://timneill.net/2010/11/modal-view-controller-example-part-2/

Comment: It answered. Many thanks. I already read this paper on apple KB, but in my case, using Openframeworks as the delegate, I was a bit confused. But I guess, following the part 1, I can do that right now. pushing my experience here after that :)

Comment: Andreas, I implemented that following the part 1 only (my delegate is already okay using OF). It works fine except something:

When I'm dismissing the modal view (= when I close my menu), even if my view containing the menu button is a very little one (it has the size of the button, basically), I cannot have access and touch anything on the screen except the button... I mean, this view seems to be on all the underneath view, disabling any interaction possibility.

This is not the case at the beginning, but appears to be the case after my first menu showing and dismissing cycle.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand your last comment. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry about my description. I'm retrying better: I meant, the view loaded as modal has to be only over a part of the screen, not all the screen. So, and I guess it is an ugly hack, I found my way using 
`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 85, 41)];
}` in order to "crop" the view before the load.

Comment: Oh, then I understand the approach you were trying on before I mentioned the modal view controller.